# How can I explicitly disable compilation of _tkinter.c when compiling Python 2.4.3 on CentOS 5?

Tags: python, compilation, tkinter

I'm trying to explicitly disable the compilation of the _tkinter module when compiling Python 2.4.3. It's easy enough to do by modifying the makefile but I'd rather just append a configuration option to avoid supplying a patch.

I do not understand the complex interplay between Modules/Setup*, setup.py and their contribution to the generation of makefile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately I suspect you can't do it without editing *some* file or other -- it's not a `configure` option we wrote in as far as I recall (I hope I'm wrong and somebody else snuck it in while I wasn't looking but a quick look at the configure file seems to confirm they didnt'). Sorry -- we never thought that somebody (with all the tk libraries installed, otherwise tkinter gets skipped) would need to deliberately avoid building _tkinter:-(. In retrospect, we clearly were wrong, so I apologize.